# Avoid chapter in new page

Tags: formatting, memoir, chapters

Hello i would like to prevent the new chapter begins in a new page, i am using `memoir` class and here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,openany,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}%insertion d'images
\usepackage{titlesec}
\graphicspath{{Annexes/images/}} %directory of the images
\usepackage{lipsum} %paragraphes prédéfinis
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                           {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                               {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\lipsum
\chapter{yes no}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Start new chapter on same page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24066)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Multiple chapters per page, only if they “fit”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245808/69818) as well.

Comment: thanks for your answers, i tried both solutions and nonde did work.

Comment: Try `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage`. This will make all subsequent clear double pages insert only one new page. If you are likely to need this later then "save" a copy of `\cleardoublepage` by first typing `\let\originalcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage`  and then `\let\cleardoublepage\originalcleardoublepage` when you ant to restore this feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using `memoir`, you simply have to redefine `\clearforchapter` using, for example

```
\gdef\clearforchapter{}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,openany,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\gdef\clearforchapter{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Additionally, you might also want to change the page style; in this case, use

```
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{<style>}
```

where `<style>` is the page style you want for the pages containing the beginning of a chapter.

Comment: Thank you ,just one last question, how can i keep the page style the same, like the headings and page numbers wont shift to the bottom?

Comment: @Hamza.w You're welcome. Use `\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{<style>}`, where `<style>` is the desired style. For example,  `\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{headings}` will use the `headings` style in those pages.