# Optional newpage command

Tags: macros, page-breaking

Does there exist a command (which I will call `\newpageoptional`) which acts in the following way:

```
    Text and code 1

    \newpageoptional{
    Text and code 2
    }

    Text and code 3
```

The effect should be:

1. If "Text and code 2" can fit on the current page, no effect.
2. If "Text and code 2" cannot fit on the current page, then all of "Text and code 2" is moved to the next page.

Comment: If you put the second block in a minipage, wouldn't the result be just the same?

Comment: maybe something can be done using the `needspace` package.

Comment: I assume the second code block should be shifted completely and not be broken, if there is no space left?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes that is right.

Comment: What about the third block? What is meant to happen to that?

Comment: You probably want `\raggedbottom`.

Answer (score 5):

It’s a bit sad to see how easily people are inclined to forget the good ol’ ways of doing things…  Seriously, this question (like [others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245774/69818) I have already seen on TeX.SX) looks like a classical problem which is discussed, and solved, on page 111 of *The TeXbook*, where the `\filbreak` command is introduced.  Quoting from there:

> The most interesting macro that plain TeX provides for page make-up is
>   called `\filbreak`.  It means, roughly, “Break the page here and fill
>   the bottom with blank space, unless there is room for more copy that
>   is itself followed by `\filbreak`.”  Thus if you put \filbreak at the
>   end of every paragraph, and if your paragraphs aren’t too long, every
>   page break will occur between paragraphs, and TeX will fit as many
>   paragraphs as possible on each page.  The precise meaning of
>   `\filbreak` is
>
> `\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg`
>
> according to Appendix B; and this simple combination of TeX’s
>   primitives produces the desired result…

The `\filbreak` macro is defined in LaTeX too (in `ltplain.dtx`), and the definition is exactly the same as that of Appendix B of *The TeXbook*:

```
\def\filbreak{\par\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg}
```

So you could just use it in your documents, without loading any package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\filbreak
\lipsum[2]\filbreak
\lipsum[3]\filbreak
\lipsum[4]\filbreak
\lipsum[5]\filbreak
\lipsum[6]\filbreak
\lipsum[7]\filbreak
\lipsum[8]\filbreak

\end{document}
```

This works as expected; but one might object that it requires typing `\filbreak` at the end of every paragraph.  Well, of course this can be made automatic:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\filbreak{\@@par\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \let\par\filbreak
    \lipsum[1-32]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Obviously, it is necessary to redefine `\filbreak` to invoke `\@@par`, instead of `\par`, to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: `\filbreak` has the small defect of being difficult to turn off. There are several answers that mention it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=filbreak

Comment: How would a `\newpageoptional` look? I mean, you are inserting `\filbreak` between every paragraph, what if you want only one paragraph? Just add `\filbreak<paragraph>\filbreak`?

Comment: @Manuel: It depends on what should happen to the following paragraphs: should they be moved unconditionally to the next page?  This is probably what egreg refers to when he speaks of `\filbreak` “being difficult to turn off”.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsavebox\TBox
\newcommand\newpageoptional[1]{%
     \savebox\TBox{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}}% to get the height of the text
     \needspace{\dimexpr\ht\TBox+\dp\TBox}%  totalheight
     #1}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\newpageoptional{%
    Text and code 2 with blindtext
    \blindtext
}

       Text and code 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly better: `\setbox\TBox=\vbox{#1}` and then just checking `\ht\TBox`.

Comment: Not really: `\parbox` sets the parindent to zero. With `\vbox` all settings are preserved.

Comment: LaTeX uses `\maxdepth=5pt`. If you want to be fussy, check whether the depth is above 5pt and add the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want `\raggedbottom` which means that when there's no space for something in a page a new one is open without *flushing* the contents to align to the bottom. Plus a `{minipage}` environment (which doesn't break across pages). Just put `\raggedbottom` in the preamble and use

```
\newcommand\newpageoptional[1]
   {\par\noindent\xdef\svparindent{\the\parindent}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\parindent\svparindent
      #1\par\xdef\svprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}%
    \end{minipage}\par\prevdepth\svprevdepth}
```

(Info about all those extra commands around the `minipage` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/21930).)